# Do I need to sanitize user inputs when using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am creating a login form that does not require the page to reload on submit. I am doing this using Ajax. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
  <form id="myForm" method="post">
     Username:    <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/><br/>
     Password:   <input name="password" id="password" type="password"/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS/Ajax:

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { username: username, password: password},
    function(data) {
     $('#results').html(data);
     $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

PHP (submit.php):

```
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                     if(password_verify($password, $row["password"]))
                     {  
                          //return true;  
                          $_SESSION["username"] = $username;  
                          $_SESSION["uuid"] = $row["uuid"];  
                          echo "success";
                          header ("location: https://durzst.com/main");
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
                          //return false;  
                          echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details")</script>';  
                     }  
                }  
           }
```

I am already sanitizing the inputs in my PHP (Yes, I will be switching to prepared statements later), but do I need to do anything with the Ajax, such as sanitizing inputs, in order to prevent any kind of attacks. If so, how?

Comment: First rule is you can never trust anything sent from the client. You can sanitize client side for user convenience but user can easily bypass anything you do in client. The only truly safe place to sanitize is server side

Comment: "You can only attempt validation on the client-side, but you must truly validate on the server-side. " - Mr. Myagi

Comment: Always use prepared statements too.

Comment: @Bren I mentioned in my post that I am indeed planning on using prepared statements.

Comment: Ajax is not intended to process login information like this. This will not work as the `submit.php` will process the post but will not return any data back to you as you are sending the page with `header()` function to somewhere thus impossible to sending back data to the main page that called the ajax.

Comment: @charlietfl So it is not worth it to sanitize the Ajax if I take proper precaution in my PHP? (Ex Prepared Statements)

Comment: @ajsoler What alternatives do I have for processing a login for like this without reloading it?

Comment: Sanitizing as much as you can before sending to the server will save traffic, but you still must not assume that your code is the only source of that traffic. There is always a workaround.

Comment: Why do you need not reloading the page when user submits credentials in the first place? The whole purpose of a login is to 1)submit the information (username and password), 2)process the information(usually with a database that has the usernames and passwords stored) 3)if validation ok, then redirect the user to intended area. So the whole point is to submit information that reloads something in the browser.

Comment: @ajsoler The page uses lots of animations. If a user doesn't exist or the password is wrong, then the page refreshes and shows the appropriate error. (If all is well, the user is redirected.) However when the page refreshes to display an error, all these animations restart. I have not found a way for css animations to continue on from where they left off before a page restart. The main concern is a css gradient background that is animated.

Comment: In such case, what you have to do is process the login information like you where doing on `submit.php` but instead of redirecting the user there, return a json object to the original ajax function and make that function redirect the user depending on the information on the json object.

Comment: @ajsoler I have seen some approaches that set a session variable in the submit.php page that contain the error messages (like the json object might contain). The main login page sees that session variable, and acts accordingly. Might that work? I have not used JSON objects with php before. How secure are they?

Comment: php sessions work on the same premise of a setting a global variable like the $_POST or $_GET, for them to be set, the page needs to be reloaded. The idea of returning a json object was only to return an "ok the user and password match" kind of response, not actually returning the credentials themselves.

Comment: Got it. I will try to figure out the JSON objects.

Comment: Bon voyage my friend. Hope you can make it work. ^^

Comment: @ajsoler On the main page, can I decode the json pacage from submit.php using PHP, or do I have to use AJAX. If I must use AJAX, how can I make it perform certain actions like setting a php session variable for the username?

Comment: get the array with php and then use the `json_encode` function to return the json object to the calling ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, always Sanitize & **Validate** your data. Both Client Side and Server Side.

***Sanitize*** your data, so you don't get unexpected formats, symbols etc.

***Validate*** your data, to ensure it's data your program expects/accepts. An email address vs some random string, a date vs a string or phone number etc.

I suggest, reading up on the subject, a quick google will get you started, also StackOverflow has tones of articles on the subject, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577959/what-is-the-difference-between-sanitizing-and-validation-in-php/32578123) is one.

I say always, and both Client Side and Server Side, not because you should trust your Client Side sanitization and validation, on the server, but you want to ensure both of your applications operate on correctly formatted and valid data.